# Calculating the rightmost digits of Graham's number

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

Through some miscellaneous reading I have stumbled upon Graham's number and more precisely, a method of calculating the $d$ rightmost digits of the number. The exact method of calculation seems straightforward through modular exponentiation. However, there is the claim that **all** power towers of height at least $d + 2$ will have their $d$ rightmost digits constant and independent of the topmost term of the tower. (At the risk of being too verbose, I redirect you to the Wikipedia article on [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number), bottom section.) I was wondering if anyone can provide a proof for the given statement.

Comment: This should follow from an iterated application of Carmichael's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4135343/16397) elsewhere is directly related and gives a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That passage in wikipedia is referenced, and [the reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20180728074456/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51625.html) includes a discussion on why that's true.

Comment: The proof in the reference doesn't seem to cover the case where the topmost term is arbitrary. That is, the proof seems to break down if $f(0) \neq p$