# Clarify a step in proving $\forall n\ge 1,$ the sequence $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}}, \dots$ is eventually constant $\pmod n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, tetration

The [1991 USAMO Problem 3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1991_USAMO_Problems/Problem_3) offers a concise proof-by-contradiction that if $n$ is any positive integer, then the sequence $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}}, \dots$ is eventually constant $\pmod n$. However, I don't fully understand the following step in that proof:

**Claim**: If the sequence $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}},\dots$ is *not* eventually constant $\pmod n$, then the sequence of its exponents $1, 2, 2^2, 2^{2^2},\dots$ is *not* eventually constant $\pmod k$, where $k$ is the eventual period of $2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3,\dots\pmod n$.

Equivalently: If $1, 2, 2^2, 2^{2^2},\dots$ *is* eventually constant $\pmod k,$ then $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}},\dots$ *is* eventually constant $\pmod n.$

Equivalently: If $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^{2^2}},\dots$ *is* eventually constant $\pmod k,$ then this same sequence *is* eventually constant $\pmod n.$

I'm sorry if this is something obvious/elementary, but would someone please explain why this is true when $n\gt 1?$ How exactly does the claim then depend on $k$ being the eventual period of $2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3,\dots\pmod n?$

Comment: If the exponents $e_i$ are eventually all of the form $km_i+r$ for fixed $r$ and some $m_i$, then $2^{e_i}=2^{km_i+r}=2^{k(m_i-1)+r}=...=2^{r}\pmod{n}$, where each equation is using that $k$ is the period modulo $n$.

Comment: What I find confusing is whether the proof shows why such a $k$ would exist in the first place? If it is shown to exist, wouldn't that conclude the proof in itself since $2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}...$ is a subsequence of $2^0, 2^1, 2^2...$?

Comment: @acephalous It's simply asserted that for all integers $b>1$, the sequence $2^0, 2^1, 2^2, \dots$ is eventually cyclic $\pmod b$, with $k$ defined as the corresponding period. (Of course a subsequence of such a periodic sequence need not be *constant*.)

Comment: @plop Thank you -- I think that's all there is to it! We have $2^{km_i+r}=2^{k(m_i-1)+r}$, etc., just *because* $k$ is the eventual period of $2^0, 2^1, 2^2,2^3,\ldots\pmod n\ \ $ (don't know why I couldn't see that).

Comment: I just discovered this may be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1160795/16397 (voting to close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power towers might distract your attention from what is *really* happening, which is just this:

> If $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ is strictly increasing and eventually constant modulo $k$, then $2^{a_1}, 2^{a_2}, 2^{a_3},\ldots$ is eventually constant modulo $n$.

**Proof.** By definition $k$ has the property that $(2^i \bmod n)_i$ eventually has period $k$, which is the same as saying that if $A$ is large enough we will have $2^A \equiv 2^{A+k} \pmod n$.

But that means that if we go far enough in the increasing sequence $a_i$ we eventually reach a point where $a_i$ is large enough to this for happen. And if we go far enough for this to happen *and* for $(a_i)$ to become constant modulo $k$, we will forever have $a_{i+1}=a_i+jk$ for some $j$, and therefore
$$ 2^{a_i} \equiv 2^{a_i+k} \equiv 2^{a_i+2k} \equiv \cdots \equiv 2^{a_i+jk} = 2^{a_{i+1}} \pmod n$$