# Prove $c,c^c,c^{c^c},c^{c^{c^c}},\ldots \pmod p$ with $p$ prime has period $1$ or $2$

Tags: number-theory, tetration

Suppose $p$ is a prime number and $c$ is some constant value which is coprime to $p$. I found that $c,c^c,c^{c^c},c^{c^{c^c}},\ldots \bmod p$ have period $1$ or $2$.

In other words, it seems sequence,$(\ ^nc )_{\geq1}$, have period $1$ or $2$.

Can we prove this?

The code which I used is here: [link](http://wandbox.org/permlink/VLWZrrutUiQaL7NV)

Comment: Are you specifically taking each $a_j$ to be between $0$ and $p$? If $p=3$ and $c=2$ and $a_0=1$, then the $a_n$ alternate back and forth between $2$ and $1$.

Comment: The limit is simply the solution of the problem $c^x\mod (p)=x$

Comment: I'm sorry. I specifically choose $a_0=c$ in the code. I change the statement of question now.

Comment: In the example Mindlack provides even with $a_{0}=c=3$ we don't have a solution. I see it as a problem of fixed points, you could even reinterpret it as a problem in Group theory by considering then as permutations if you don't want to apply number theory.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the numerical data you were dealing with.

Comment: May I suspect, that you actually work with $c \pmod p$, $c^c \pmod p$,$c^{c^c} \pmod p$ ,$ \cdots \pmod p$ instead? (Note that this formulation against yours gives different results, possibly according better to your proof -intent and I remember to have looked at this in the context of modular tetration sometime ago and might have seen the constant sequence for many examples)

Comment: >Gottfried Helms I'm sorry for confusing. Yes.

Comment: Ah, well, so possibly you better use the notation (known from discussion of tetration) $a_n(c,p)= \,^n c \pmod p \qquad \text{ for } n>0 $ and whether $a_{n+1}(c,p)=a_n(c,p) \qquad \text{for } n \gt n_0$ with some $n_0$

Comment: I check the sequence once again and it's not converge at all. The period is 1 or 2.I add code which I used. https://wandbox.org/permlink/VLWZrrutUiQaL7NV

Comment: ueir - if my previous comment is what really happened then you might also add the tag `tetration`to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I add a tag and change the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**
If you actually wanted to prove that $ \,^nc \pmod p$ converge to a constant sequence then the following might help for a proof:

assume $p=7$, $c=5$
Then what you ask for is whether $\{5, 5^5 , 5^{5^5}, ...\} \pmod 7$ converge to a constant sequence.
This is a question of recursive application of *"order of cyclic subgroup"* :

- we know $5^k \pmod 7= 5 ^ { k \pmod {\varphi(7)}}\pmod 7= 5 ^ { k \pmod 6}\pmod 7$
- Now if $k$ is itself a power of $5$ then we ask furtherly for the residues of $k=5^j \pmod 6$.
- we find that this is $5^{j \pmod 2} \pmod 6$
- And one step higher this becomes a constant sequence.

Here it is surely meaningful to try a proof. (I think, this should be easy to derive one from that example)

---

### *old version*   (removed. You can see it in the "edit-history")

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159995/do-the-last-digits-of-exponential-towers-really-converge-to-a-fixed-sequence/1160327#1160327) seems to show that the sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: The key fact is $\phi(p),\phi(\phi(p)),\phi(\phi(\phi(p))),\ldots$ is strictly decreasing sequence until it becomes 1. Then, maybe there is some mistake in the code. Thank you.

Comment: @pregunton - a very nice answer you've found! Perhaps it could be a bit shaped (upps my comment crossed with that last one of ueir)

Answer (score 1):

That’s false. Consider $c=3$ and $p=7$. Note that $c^2=2$, $c^4=4$ mod $7$. So depending on the value of $a_0$, you can have two constant sequences. Worse: with $a_0=3$, the sequence is a cycle $3,6,1,3,6,1,\ldots$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I specifically choose $a_0=c$ in the code. I change the statement of question now.