# Proving $\forall d\in\mathbb{Z_+},\ \min\{n:\lambda^n(10^d)=1\}=d+2,$ where $\lambda()$ is the Carmichael function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, tetration

(I'm posting this question in the spirit of [this advice](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and will post an answer if no one else does so.)

[[This paper]](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/h23/h23.pdf) proves the following:

> If $k, x$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3\dots$ are positive integers, then $a_1\uparrow a_2\uparrow\dots a_{s}\uparrow x\pmod k$ is *independent of the value of $x$*, provided $s\gt h(k).$ Here $h(k):=\min\{n:\lambda^n(k)=1\}$, where $\lambda()$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Thus, if we're considering the last $d$ decimal digits of such a tower, the proviso involves $k=10^d.$ I've verified by computer that $h(10^d)=d+2$ for $1\le d\le 10^3$.

**Q**: Is it correct that $\ h(10^d)=d+2\ $ for every positive integer $d$? How to prove it? For other bases $b$ as well, are there correspondingly simple formulas for $\ h(b^d)?$

EDIT: Since my answer would essentially coincide with that of @Onir, let me instead just mention here that the same method gives the following explicit formula for $\lambda^n(10^d), \ \ n,d\in\mathbb{Z_+}:$

$$\lambda^n(10^d)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $1\le d\le n-2$}\\
2&\text{if $d=n-1$}\\
2^2\,5^{d-n}&\text{if $n\le d\le 2n-1$}\\
2^{d-2n}\,5^{d-n}&\text{if $d\ge 2n+2$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: for general $b$ it seems a bit hard, for example, if $b=p$ it would require being able to factor $p-1$, and then for each prime $q$ dividing $p-1$ we would also have to factor $q-1$ and so on

Comment: @Onir Yes, I see. What I had in mind was that there might be a few special bases of interest that might be worth the trouble.

Comment: I think for bases in which the prime divisors of $b$ are all $2$ or fermat primes we can do something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for $a\geq 4$ and $b\geq 1$ we have

$\lambda(2^a 5^b) = \operatorname{lcm}(2^{a-2},4\cdot 5^{b-1}) = 2^{a-2}5^{b-1}$.

Let $k = \lceil d/2 \rceil$.

Then $\lambda^k(10^d) = 2^25^{d-k}$

From here each application of $\lambda$ just reduces the exponent of $5$ by one, so we have:

$\lambda^d(10^d) = 2^2$

$\lambda^{d+1}(10^d) = 2$

$\lambda^{d+2}(10^d) = 1$